# How to ping the address for postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to set up postgres with docker. I want to verify the address for my database, thus I tried `ping 0.0.0.0:5432` and `ping 127.0.0.1:5432` and `ping localhost:5432`, but all returned  `Unknown host` and cannot be resolved.

Why is that? what is the correct address for postgres? My psql is running correctly.

Comment: You can't "ping" a port, you can only ping an IP address. To check if a port is open, you can e.g. use `telnet`

Comment: But the port should belongs to an IP address. what is that?

Comment: The IP address is the ```0.0.0.0``` or ```127.0.0.1```.   The problem is, without specific details on how you deployed the postgres db, it's hard to tell if that is the right IP.  Also, this question seems more appropriate for Serverfault,

Comment: `ping` only tests if an IP address [is reachable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_(networking_utility)) via TCP/IP. It doesn't use ports for that. Please read up on the TCP protocol, ports, IP addresses and how they work together. To check if a port is open (on a specific IP address) you need to use `telnet` (for remote hosts) or `netstat` (for local ports)

Comment: Many servers/firewalls are configured not to respond to `ping`, as it does have malicious uses.  You said psql is working.  So then what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from the question, but if the database is running in the docker container, make sure you exposed the 5432 port to the host machine. Use `--expose` if you are starting container with `docker run ...` ([doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/)) or add

```
ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

to your docker-compose file ([doc](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/))